# Using a typedef'd struct in a template

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I have a structure that id like to pass to an object instance, so after defining my structure

```
struct Element
{ 
   floatPTR Quizes;
   int quizLimit;
   string fullName;
};
```

And later, I have a `typedef Element* elementPTR;`

Followed by my class definition:

```
template<typename elementPTR>;
class Array
{
public:
    stuff
private:
    elementPTR foo;
    stuff
};
```

When I compile, I get the error: `error: expected unqualified-id before ‘;’ token` for the line at: `template<typename elementPTR>;`

Am I missing something? I thought this was a legal operation.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried deleting semicolon (`;`) after `template<typename elementPTR>`

Comment: Re: "I have a typedef Element* elementPTR"  *Gross.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `;` at the end.

```
template<typename elementPTR>
class Array
{
public:
    stuff
private:
    elementPTR foo;
    stuff
};
```

Comment: There's an ambiguity between the template argument and the `typedef`?

Comment: @Snps: No, there's no ambiguity. Within the template the name refers to the parameter, which hides the typedef.

Comment: Thanks! Cpp is iffy with where semicolons go.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra `;` in `template<typename elementPTR>;` . Just remove it.

But from your example, I don't see a reason to use template this way.